# Synapse on Loki

Tags: release-loki, wingpanel, desktop

I tried to install Synapse on Loki editing the ppa, installed the required libgee2 and libgranite, but all I get was to broke the wingpanel.
Any solution to have a nice search engine on Elementary Loki?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try **Albert**
it's an alternative to synapse

Comment: I installed Albert via ppa. Seems pretty much the same as Synapse, and it have a nice configuration panel!